# How to solve ElasticSearch login problem?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to install ElasticSearch on my mac.

I downloaded the tar from the [official website](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch) and extract it.

Then I run the bin/elastic. After that I open https://localhost:9200/ and it displays the input field for username and password when I canceled it, this appears:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "security_exception",
        "reason": "missing authentication credentials for REST request [/]",
        "header": {
          "WWW-Authenticate": [
            "Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\"",
            "Bearer realm=\"security\"",
            "ApiKey"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "type": "security_exception",
    "reason": "missing authentication credentials for REST request [/]",
    "header": {
      "WWW-Authenticate": [
        "Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\"",
        "Bearer realm=\"security\"",
        "ApiKey"
      ]
    }
  },
  "status": 401
}
```

I did not put a password or username and I look at the previous questions about that and no one is working for me.
What should I do?

Note: When I open http://localhost:9200/ it displays:

```
This page isn’t working localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Tldr;

Seems like [Elasticsearch create a password automatically](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/built-in-users.html#bootstrap-elastic-passwords).

You may want to set you own with

```
bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive
```

But in version `8.x` and above [it is deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-passwords.html#:%7E:text=Deprecated%20in%208.0.&text=To%20manually%20reset%20the%20password,for%20the%20built%2Din%20users.).

You should be using

```
elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive
```

Comment: It says:
`
Failed to authenticate user 'elastic' against https://192.168.189.36:9200/_security/_authenticate?pretty
Possible causes include:
 * The password for the 'elastic' user has already been changed on this cluster
 * Your elasticsearch node is running against a different keystore
   This tool used the keystore at /Users/eda.deniz.celik/Downloads/elasticsearch-8.2.1/config/elasticsearch.keystore

You can use the `elasticsearch-reset-password` CLI tool to reset the password of the 'elastic' user`

Comment: Then I guess you should use the `elasticsearch-reset-password`

Answer (score 1):

If the Elastic Search Setup is on Windows Then I followed these steps to resolve the issue of authentication

1. Open Command Prompt as Administrator
2. Go to the Elastic search unzipped folder bin path `cd elasticsearch-bin-folderpath`
3. `bin>elasticsearch-users useradd username -p password -r superuser`
4. `bin>elasticsearch`

Open `https:localhost:9200/` in browser

when prompted for username and password give the username and password set after by useradd command